# The Terminal: uma sala de chat para usuários dos sites internacionais

Tags: debate

*Traduzido de [The Terminal: a chat room for international site users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317209/the-terminal-a-chat-room-for-international-site-users)*

---

[image]

Um dos principais fatores do [nosso successo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316522/274323) é a comunicação efetiva. Gostaria de anunciar a sala de chat “[The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)”. É um lugar para os usuários dos sites internacionais e qualquer um que seja apaixonado por essas comunidades. Ao criar esta sala, eu gostaria de melhorar o seguinte:

1. *Comunicação entre as comunidades*. Acho que precisamos criar um lugar onde as comunidades internacionais podem [discutir seus problemas do dia-a-dia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317116/274323) e se conhecer de maneira rápida e informal.
2. *Entender o que vocês precisam*. A melhor forma de entender o que uma comunidade precisa é escutar seus usuários. Tenho a impressão que estou perdendo algumas coisas que acontecem nos metas internacionais. Se você acha que eu, como funcionário, preciso dar uma olhada em algo no seu meta, por favor me avise na sala do chat.
3. *Ajuda em tempo hábil*. Eu me sinto mal quando os usuários das comunidades internacionais não conseguem falar no chat com alguém da empresa quando eles precisam de ajuda com o site. Chame-me na sala de chat sempre que você precisar de ajuda.

Por favor, [junte-se ao chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)! Conheça outros usuários dos sites internacionais e me diga como posso ajudá-lo!

**Post nos outros metas**

- [SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3714/) (agradecimentos a [Robert Columbia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/336163/robert-columbia))

Comment: Ele podia ter dito qual a língua oficial do chat. È fácil entrar e ver, mas o texto ficaria mais completo.

Comment: @Maniero Concordo, coloquei um [comentário sobre isso](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317209/the-terminal-a-chat-room-for-international-site-users#comment1042645_317209) no post original

Comment: @Maniero As regras foram colocadas [no próprio chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47288083#47288083) e a resposta é: [qualquer idioma pode ser usado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317209#comment1043500_317209)

Comment: Vixi, "qualquer idioma pode ser usado", teremos uma torre de Babel. o.o

Comment: @carla A princípio também achei estranho, mas acho que decidiram assim pq há muitos usuários dos sites internacionais que não falam inglês, e se a ideia do chat é que todos estes usuários participem, parece que não tem muito jeito...